# How to simulate the CNY70 IR reflectometer with TINA or LTSpice

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, infrared, photodiode

How can I model the [CNY70](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83751/cny70.pdf) IR reflectometer from Vishay (click here for datasheet) using [TINA](https://www.ti.com/tool/TINA-TI) or [LTSpice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html).

In particular, I would like to simulate the circuit shown below:
[image]

The 4pins on the left side connect to the CNY70. The circuit amplifies the signal from the  CNY70 transistor. It is just a reference circuit that should work out of the box.

EDIT: I have simulated the circuit using TINA:
[image]

I have modeled the CNY70 as resistor with values between 0 and 100k and got the following voltage for the output signal:
[image]

Despite the resistance of the CNY70 changes, I get no chance in the amplification. More realistically, the transistor is modelled as current source (probably) but I thought a simple resistor could also do.

Comment: You could try to model a transistor with a current source in the base, meant to represent the flux. I'm not home right now, but a quick look over the datasheet looks like it could be done with a regular transistor, maybe slightly tweaked.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thank you a lot, please see my edit. It would help me a lot if you can help me with the simulation.

Answer (score 2):

What I meant was to use a transistor with a current source in the base, which is meant to represent the luminosity. Something like this:

[image: test]

This is not meant to represent the CNY70, rather to show how it could be done. You will need much more than a wet finger in the wind (my approach) to model the diode and the transistor (I used some round numbers; the β is too low). As it is now it roughly has 1m <> 50u, 10m <> 500u, 100m <> 5m (compare with fig. 5 in the datasheet). At any rate, the value for `F1` will set the amount of luminosity in the base, and because the law is logarithmic by nature, you should get something similar to fig. 9 in the datasheet.